# File Resizing in Vue FilePond not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue FilePond to manage my images.
I would like to resize / Crop my image  after uploading. Following the documentation here : [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-resize/)

This is my code:

```
 <FilePond
    name="test"
    ref="pond"
    :maxFiles="max || 1"
    labelIdle="Drop files here..."
    allowMultiple="false"
    acceptedFileTypes="image/jpeg, image/png"
   
    v-bind:files="myFiles"
    v-on:addfile="add"
    imagePreviewHeight = "200"
    allowImagePreview ="true"
    allowImageCrop="true"
    imageCropAspectRatio="1:1"
    allowImageResize="true"
    imageResizeTargetWidth="200"
    imageResizeTargetHeight="200"
    imageResizeMode="contain"
    imageResizeUpscale="false"
    v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"/>
```

In Method, i catch the file in FilePond to transfer it to an Object.  In FilePond, the image is cropped correctly, but the file transfered isn't. Seems lik eI'm catching the source file.

In Method :

```
 add: function(fieldName, file) {
     let $this= this
     console.log('#', file.file)
     var ref = this
     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file.file); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
     ref.addproject.image= reader.result;
     console.log('yy',reader.result);
     }
     },
```

Here is the cropped Image  in Filepond Preview
[image]

**My Problem** : In Result i got the original File, not the cropped/resized image like in the Preview.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you forgot to register the [image transform plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-transform/)? Without it, FilePond doesn't do clientside image transforms.

Comment: This worked for me, I think the documentation should be more specific and clear about this. Thank you!